# Determine which store (ie country) an iphone app was purchased from?

Tags: iphone

For business reasons the project I'm working on has the requirement to determine which country's itunes store an app has been purchased from.

Knowing where the user is at the time of purchase (via location services etc) is not suitable and they would prefer to have 1 universal binary rather than having to have a separate binary for every store.

Is this something the application can determine at run-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the specific answer is ***NO. You can NOT get the app store country.*** (As of mid-2010.)

For general readers, the following could be useful ... it is quite a nuisance to collect exactly these code three fragments together:

```
// to ("usually") get the preferred language from those we supplied in bundle
// [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0]

// to ("often") get the preferred language regardless
// [ [NSBundle preferredLocalizationsFromArray:[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes]] objectAtIndex:0]

// to ("fairly reliably") get the user's chosen language setting...
// [ [NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]
```

Cheers

Comment: I don't think that would solve the problem unless dealing with fairly limited languages. I.e. the particular app store would have to restrict the languages of the apps it sold. @Roger wants to know which store sold the item. The localised languages that the app contains would not be effected by that.

Comment: We're already using localizations extensively thanks. To clarify, the position is that we would like to have an app that self-configures depending on which country it has been purchased from. We already do the self-configuration based on where the user currently is (from location services) but a legal requirement has arisen that requires this configuration to depend on the country of purchase, rather than the country of use. Obviously we could have a different app for every country, but that is a bit of a headache.

Comment: I suspected that was probably the case ... thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: It's now mid-2012 - has this changed?

Comment: NO, you can not get the app store country.  Unless the policy utterly changes, you will not be able to. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried hidden using in-app purchases to determine the store?

Comment: We need to know at the point the app is downloaded, so that won't help.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, could this be regarded as a violation of a customers right to privacy? I would imagine you have already looked at the reporting done back to you from the app store. If it's not in that data, I would imagine you won't be able to get it.

Comment: Don't see how it violates any privacy terms, we need to know the country because legally we are required to limit services in certain territories and the legal agreements pertain to the store the app is purchased in, not the location the user happens to be in at any given time. This information is not associated with any user identifiable data so no privacy issues.

Obviously we can do this by having a different binary for each store, but that's potentially a lot of different binaries to supply to apple when a single one would do the trick if we knew where it came from ...